# Java Socket programming java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out

Tags: java, exception, tcp, socket.io, client-server

I'm new to java and building a microservice in java that reads messages from ActiveMQ and send the message as a TCP packet to another server using socker programming. I'm able to successfully read the message from ActiveMQ however after sending a few TCP packets I get 'Operation timed out' exception.  Please let me know what can be done to resolve this?

```
App.java


package com.example;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.jms.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class App
{
private static String url = "tcp://172.13.0.1:61616";
private static String topicName = "topic/CNAAlarms";
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        connectToActiveMQ(url, topicName);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("for connectToActiveMQ == " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("------------");
    }
}
public static void connectToActiveMQ(String url, String topicName) throws JMSException {
    System.out.println("inside connectToActiveMQ");
    System.out.println("url = " + url);
    System.out.println("topicName = " + topicName);
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setUserName("abc@abc");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("abc");
    connectionFactory.setClientID("testingClient");
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(url);
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    System.out.println("connected");
    connection.start(); 
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    System.out.println("session created");
    Topic topic = session.createTopic(topicName);
    TopicSubscriber durablSubscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, topicName);
    System.out.println("durable subscriber created");
    MessageListener listener = new Listener();
    durablSubscriber.setMessageListener(listener);
  
}
public static void sendDataToTCPServer(String data){
   // initialize socket and output streams
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside SendDataToTCPServer");
        Socket s = new Socket("abc123d.it.internal", 11201);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeUTF(data);
        dos.close();
        s.close();

    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

Listener.java


package com.example;
import javax.jms.*;
public class Listener implements MessageListener{
public void onMessage(Message message){
    try{
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            String text = textMessage.getText();
            System.out.println("Received text: " + text);
            App.sendDataToTCPServer("activemq-bridge :" + text + "\n");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);
            App.sendDataToTCPServer("activemq-bridge :" +message + "\n");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("for onMessage Listener: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}



Output:

Received text: {"userName":null,"enterpriseName":"ABC"}
Inside SendDataToTCPServer
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:585)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:507)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:287)
    at com.example.App.sendDataToTCPServer(App.java:98)
    at com.example.Listener.onMessage(Listener.java:12)
    at    org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1321)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:129)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: 1. Can you ping `172.13.0.1`? 2. Can you Telnet to `172.13.0.1 port 61616`? Hint: this is not a coding problem.

Comment: yes, its reachable. I can connect to the port. I added dos.writeUTF(data + "\n"); to my code and I think it has worked. have not seen this error since then, still observing.